# How can I add a Workspace Browser to a MATLAB app or emulate one?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

MATLAB apps such as the Signal Analyzer feature a Workspace Browser panel which shows variables in the base workspace that can be used as inputs for the app's functionality. I want to build an app that has this same functionality.

Is this a component that can be added directly to `uifigure` windows?

If not, I can see that information about the contents of the base workspace can be obtained from `evalin`:

```
S = evalin("base","whos");
```

The resulting contents in `S` would evidently be enough to display a listing, and further calls to `evalin` on selection of one of the variables would provide access to their value.

However, the Workspace Browser panels in MATLAB apps also update when the contents of the base workspace changes. Is there an event notifying the panel of the need to update that my code can listen to too?

Comment: related: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/278329-how-can-i-insert-workspace-window-inside-a-gui#answer_217356

Comment: S is a nx1 array with between the others a name field. You can get the names of the workspace variables and display them as in dropdown menu. Upon selection callback you eval the needed variable/s from workspace. Just an idea tho

Comment: @FerroLuca yes, the question if using `evalin` to emulate the browser is how to keep the display up to date when the workspace changes, per last para

Comment: What specific functionality do you want to emulate? Does the updating need to be instantaneous or would a "refresh" button or regular timer check suffice? Do you want to be able to update the base workspace variables or just read them? Could you limit it to a specific set of variables to "monitor" or do you need the whole workspace? Mirroring the whole base workspace in real time will likely be tricky, providing some acceptable limitations will make your life easier, and allow you to search for specific help like dynamic class properties and event listeners

Comment: @Wolfie I think possible solutions based on polling/refreshing the workspace speak for themselves. I'm interested in any mechanism that would trigger code capable of updating the display instantly when the contents of the workspace changes. This is how "official" apps behave. Responding to changes to a subset of existing workspace variables would be an acceptable limitation.

Comment: You might find [this comment thread on UndocumentedMatlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog_old/customizing-matlabs-workspace-table#comment-57828) interesting, at the time of writing Yair wasn't aware of a way to monitor workspace changes directly, which doesn't bode well. You might be able to run with the suggestion in that thread though of monitoring the underlying workspace table for change events. Although I'm not sure why you've dismissed polling approaches, that's probably the simplest answer. Just because the MATLAB IDE can do something natively, doesn't mean us mortals can do it too

Comment: @Wolfie not dismissing polling entirely but it's an inelegant solution which is the motivation for the question. I live in hope that interfaces have been introduced since that thread was conducted. After all the Signal Analyzer didn't show up until 2016 and doesn't give the impression of running as part of the base IDE. Latching onto the Java components in the IDE may indeed be a solution, perhaps inelegant in other respects! I'll investigate...

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd probably recommend using a class with its own "workspace" anyway, whether that be a struct property which houses all the variables or using a class with dynamic properties. Then you avoid muddying your base workspace, and you can attach event listeners to the class properties being updated

Comment: @Wolfie there are pros and cons to different modes of selecting inputs but I think the fact that several apps within MATLAB itself choose this particular one is as good a reason as any not to dismiss it out of hand.